# RxJava2 success always called twice

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, mvp, rx-android

I'm implementing an MVP architecture with Retrofit, and RxJava2 (with RxAndroid). I have the following setup

`NetworkInterface.java` where retrofit calls lie

```
public interface NetworkInterface {
    @GET("/input")
    Single<List<InformationData>> getInfoData();
}
```

`InformationDataDao.java` Data access layer for the information data

```
@Dao
public interface InformationDataDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    Completable createInfoData(List<InformationData> infoData);
}
```

`MainPresenter.java` where the calls are being made public class MainPresenter {

```
    public MainPresenter() {

    }

    // Method called to initialize the subscription
    @Override
    public void subscribe() {
        this.collectInfoData();
    }

    private void collectInfoData() {
        Single<List<InformationData>> singleInfoData = networkInterface.getInfoData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

        singleInfoData.subscribe(informationDatas -> {
            InformationDataDao informationDataDao = database.informationDataDao();
            informationDataDao.createInfoData(informationDatas);

            // What made me detect that this was being called twice
            Log.d(Constant.LOG_TAG, "Info Data: " + informationDatas.size());

            // Rest of the code here
        }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
    }
}
```

`SplashActivity.java` The method that calls the presenter

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Helps in getting the location
    private FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient;

    private SplashPresenter mPresenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        mPresenter = new SplashPresenter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // These three lines ensure that you have the appropriate permissions to proceed. In the third line for instance, the user will be navigated out to the settings pane to turn on location.
        // When he/she returns to the activity, the onResume is called so I'm assuming that's the best place to start the presenter
        this.ensureHasPermissions();
        boolean isGoogleServiceAvailable = this.ensureGoogleServiceAvailability();
        boolean isLocationServiceAvailable = this.ensureLocationServiceAvailable();

        if (isLocationServiceAvailable && isGoogleServiceAvailable) {
            locationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, location -> {
                        // Set the closest location and subscribe
                        presenter.setClosestLocation(location);
                        presenter.subscribe();
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

From the `SplashPresenter.java`, the log is printed twice, indicating that the complete callback was called twice. Is there any idea why this may be so? I'm quite new to RxJava2 and will greatly appreciate the feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: Check once if the `collectInfoData()` also getting called twice. You can put a log in the  ` subscribe()` method, and verify only once it calls `collectInfoData`

Comment: @SarthKn I'm sorry but I don't get what you mean. Can you perhaps point out how to go about it?

Comment: `Log.d(Constant.LOG_TAG, "Info Data: " + informationDatas.size());` this log is getting called twice right?

Comment: I commented (the DAO I mean) and looged that out and still got it being called twice

Comment: Your `singleInfoData.subscribe` is getting called twice?

Comment: The logging was done this way... `singleInfoData.subscribe(infoDatas -> Log.d(Constant.LOG_TAG, "InfoData: " + infoDatas.size());` and yes, it was called twice

Comment: What I suspected was, the overridden `subscribe()` might be getting called twice, as a result you are getting 2 calls to `this.collectInfoData();` which will end up in creating the entire Rx chain twice.
You can verify that it once by butting a log at `subscribe()` method and how many times it is getting printed

Comment: You got my point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186758/discussion-between-cr05s19xx-and-sarath-kn).